# Llenar un treeview desde un datatable en vb.net,

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un codigo en vb6 donde arma el arbol con el treeviewe y quiero  migrar  este codigo vb.net con vs2010, como haria ? anexo codigo

```
Public Function CargaArbol()
Set rs = Nothing
Set rs = frmSelectorLT.rsVerif
rs.MoveFirst

X1 = rs.Fields(0)                       'LotePT
X2 = rs.Fields(1)                       'PalletPT


If rs.Fields(2) <> "" Then
X3 = rs.Fields(2)                       'GB

If rs.Fields(3) <> "" Then
X4 = rs.Fields(3)                       'BB

If rs.Fields(4) <> "" Then
X5 = rs.Fields(4)                       'LoteMP

If rs.Fields(5) <> "" Then
X6 = rs.Fields(5)                       'PalletMP

If rs.Fields(6) <> "" Then
X7 = rs.Fields(7) & "/" & rs.Fields(6)        'OC / Lin

Else
X7 = ""
End If

Else
X6 = ""
X7 = ""
End If

Else
X5 = ""
X6 = ""
X7 = ""
End If

Else
X4 = ""
X5 = ""
X6 = ""
X7 = ""
End If

Else
X3 = ""
X4 = ""
X5 = ""
X6 = ""
X7 = ""
End If

R1 = 0
'tv1.Style = tvwTreelinesText
tv1.Style = tvwPictureText
tv1.BorderStyle = vbFixedSingle

'Corte por EOF
rs.MoveFirst
While Not rs.EOF
        R1 = R1 + 1
        Rx1 = "r" & R1
        LotePTAnt = X1
        Set imgX = ImageList1.ListImages(1)
        Set nodX = tv1.Nodes.Add(, , Rx1, "LotePT:" & X1)
        nodX.Image = 6

    'Corte por LotePT
    While (LotePTAnt = X1) And Not rs.EOF
        R2 = R2 + 1
        Rx2 = "s" & R2
        PalletPTAnt = X2
        Set nodX = tv1.Nodes.Add(Rx1, tvwChild, Rx2, "PalletPT: " & X2)
        nodX.Image = 7

        'Corte por Pallet PT
        While (PalletPTAnt = X2) And (LotePTAnt = X1) And Not rs.EOF
            If X3 <> "" Then
            R3 = R3 + 1
            Rx3 = "t" & R3
            Set nodX = tv1.Nodes.Add(Rx2, tvwChild, Rx3, "GrinderBatch :" & X3)
            nodX.Image = 5
            End If
            GrinderBatchAnt = X3

            'Corte Por GB
            While (GrinderBatchAnt = X3) And (PalletPTAnt = X2) And (LotePTAnt = X1) And Not rs.EOF
                If X4 <> "" Then
                R4 = R4 + 1
                Rx4 = "u" & R4
                Set nodX = tv1.Nodes.Add(Rx3, tvwChild, Rx4, "BlenderBatch :" & X4)
                nodX.Image = 4
                End If
                BlenderBatchAnt = X4

                'Corte por BlenderBatch
                While (BlenderBatchAnt = X4) And (GrinderBatchAnt = X3) And (PalletPTAnt = X2) And (LotePTAnt = X1) And Not rs.EOF
                    If X5 <> "" Then
                    R5 = R5 + 1
                    Rx5 = "w" & R5
                    Set nodX = tv1.Nodes.Add(Rx4, tvwChild, Rx5, "LoteMP :" & X5)
                    nodX.Image = 3
                    End If
                    LoteAnt = X5

                    'Corte por Lote MP
                    While (LoteAnt = X5) And (BlenderBatchAnt = X4) And (GrinderBatchAnt = X3) And (PalletPTAnt = X2) And (LotePTAnt = X1) And Not rs.EOF
                       If X6 <> "" Then
                       R6 = R6 + 1
                       Rx6 = "v" & R6
                       Set nodX = tv1.Nodes.Add(Rx5, tvwChild, Rx6, "PalletMP :" & X6)
                       nodX.Image = 2
                       End If
                       PalletAnt = X6

                        'Corte por PalletMP
                        While (PalletAnt = X6) And (LoteAnt = X5) And (BlenderBatchAnt = X4) And (GrinderBatchAnt = X3) And (PalletPTAnt
= X2) And (LotePTAnt = X1) And Not rs.EOF
                                If X7 <> "" Then
                                R7 = R7 + 1
                                Rx7 = "x" & R7
                                Set nodX = tv1.Nodes.Add(Rx6, tvwChild, Rx7, "OC/Lin :" & X7)
                            nodX.Image = 1
                            End If
                            OClinAnt = X7

                        'Corte por OC/Lin
                        While (OClinAnt = X7) And (PalletAnt = X6) And (LoteAnt = X5) And (BlenderBatchAnt = X4) And (GrinderBatchAnt = X3) And (PalletPTAnt = X2) And (LotePTAnt = X1) And Not rs.EOF
                                rs.MoveNext
                                If Not rs.EOF Then
                                    X1 = rs.Fields(0)                       'LotePT
                                    X2 = rs.Fields(1)                       'PalletPT
                                    If rs.Fields(2) <> "" Then
                                        X3 = rs.Fields(2)                       'GB
                                        If rs.Fields(3) <> "" Then
                                            X4 = rs.Fields(3)                       'BB
                                            If rs.Fields(4) <> "" Then
                                                X5 = rs.Fields(4)                       'LoteMP
                                                If rs.Fields(5) <> "" Then
                                                    X6 = rs.Fields(5)                       'PalletMP
                                                    If rs.Fields(6) <> "" Then
                                                        X7 = rs.Fields(7) & "/" & rs.Fields(6)        'OC / Lin
                                                    Else
                                                        X7 = ""
                                                    End If
                                                Else
                                                    X6 = ""
                                                    X7 = ""
                                                End If
                                            Else
                                                X5 = ""
                                                X6 = ""
                                                X7 = ""
                                            End If
                                        Else
                                            X4 = ""
                                            X5 = ""
                                            X6 = ""
                                            X7 = ""
                                        End If
                                    Else
                                        X3 = ""
                                        X4 = ""
                                        X5 = ""
                                        X6 = ""
                                        X7 = ""
                                    End If
                                End If
                            Wend 'Fin Corte OC/Lin
                        Wend 'Fin Corte por Pallet PT
                    Wend 'Fin Corte por Lote PT
                Wend 'Fin por Corte por Grinder Batch
            Wend  'Fin por Corte por Blender Batch
        Wend  'Fin por Corte por Pallet MP
    Wend 'Fin por Corte por Lote MP
Wend  'Fin por Corte por OC/Lin

End Function
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow! Tu pregunta ha quedado mal formateada tomate tu tiempo **editandola** para que sea **legible**

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Creo que quedaria exactamente igual. Que problema tuviste al pasarlo?